# FatalThrowableError in Testing.php line 39: Class 'App\TestingModel' not found laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am new for Laravel 5.3 and learning. Now I have created form and I want to insert form values to database through controller and model.Now i am getting all data from form to controller and i want to pass it to model.But when i pass data to model i get an error

```
"BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82:
Method [savemodel] does not exist"
```

This is my View page code:

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'Testing@store', 'method' => 'post'))}}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::submit('Submitform', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my Controller(Testing.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\TestingModel;
class testing extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        echo 'hi';
      $storeform=new TestingModel();
      $storeform->savemodel($request);


    }




}
```

This is my model(TestingModel):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TestingModel extends Model
{
   public function savemodel()
   {
       echo 'hello';exit;
   }


}
```

I don't know i am doing right way or not.How to insert data from model?Please help me

Answer (score 0):

this is my modal.

`

```
<?php`

`namespace App;`

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

`use App\UserUploads;`
`use App\FileUplods;`

`class FileUplods extends Model`  
`{`   
    `protected $table = 'upload_files';`  
     `protected $fileable = ['user_id', 'origanal_file_name' , 'sortby' , 'new_file_name_after_upload'];`

`}`


and here is my controller

`<?php`

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

`use App\Http\Requests;`

`use App\FileUplods;`

`class ImageController extends Controller`
`{`

    `public function ajaxfileupload(Request $request)`
        `{`   
            `$fileupload = new FileUplods();`
            `$fileupload->user_id = $user_id;`
            `$fileupload->origanal_file_name = $request->origanal_file_name;`
            `$fileupload->sortby = $request->sortby;`
            `$fileupload->new_file_name_after_upload = $request->new_file_name_after_upload;`
            `$fileupload->save();`
        `}`
`}
```

And this is my controller try like this this will defiantly work.

Answer (score 0):

first of add a namespace in your controller for your model

```
use App\TestingModel
```

Then your controller function would be like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //echo 'hi';
  $storeform=new TestingModel;
  $storeform->title = $request->input('title');
  $storeform->description = $request->input('description');
  $storeform->save();
 }
```

and edit your model like this

```
$table = 'table_name';
$fillable = [ 'title', 'description' ];
```

and if you want to run the function from the model then write the code like this

```
$storeform = TestingModel::savemodel();
```